# Does the set of integer powers of $\pi$ contain 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, pi

The title, but more specifically, if I were to define the group $\langle \{\pi^n | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, + \rangle$, would this satisfy the requirement for forming a group of containing an identity element? I am aware that this wouldn't form a group regardless since it isn't closed under addition.

Comment: Well... $0=\pi-\pi$, it is unclear what $\langle (),+\rangle$ means in this case...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to look at $\langle \{\pi^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, \cdot\rangle$ or maybe $\langle \{n \pi \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, +\rangle$?

Comment: $\pi$ is a transcendental number, which means that it is the root of no polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $c_0+c_1\pi+\cdots+c_n\pi^n=0$, $c_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, if and only if every $c_i$ is zero. That is: the only way $0$ can be in your "group", no matter how you form the product, is if you put it there manually. Similarly for $1$.

Comment: The confusion is caused because the question in the title of your post is different from the question in the body of the post - it is not more specific, it is a different question. The answer to the question in the title is no, but to the question in the body is yes.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S = \{\pi^n \mid n \in {\Bbb Z}\}$. You consider the additive group $\langle S \rangle$ generated by $S$. This is not very precise, but I assume you mean the subgroup of $({\Bbb R}, +)$ generated by $S$. And in this case, yes, $\langle S \rangle$ contains the identity of the ambiant group, i.e. $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not. For one, it does not contain $0$, as you contemplated. (Indeed, $\pi^n > 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z$.)
$+$ is not even a binary operation on the set. In fact, the sum of two elements of your set is *never* in the set. Indeed, if there existed integers $a, b, c$ such that $$\pi^a + \pi^b = \pi^c,$$
then multiplying with a large positive power of $\pi$ would yield $$\pi^A + \pi^B = \pi^C$$ for positive integers $A, B, C$. But $\pi$ is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) and so, it cannot satisfy the integer polynomial $x^A + x^B - x^C$.

Comment: I don't agree with this. The notation used means the additive group generated by the powers of $\pi$, and that contains $0$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: From OP's notation, it looked like $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ was being used to denote an ordered tuple. Even the way the question is phrased indicates that.